# How can I adjust Bootstrap5 right Column on top on mobile view

Tags: bootstrap-5

I’ve tried order-first and order-last. I have two cols in my row.

I want the left column to stay below in mobile view

Answer (score 0):

try this css code:
in this code **main div** is your main section in which the 2 cols so, please replace your **main div** class.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {  .main div{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse; } }
```

Comment: That didn’t work also

Comment: please show your bootstrap code, then I can resolve this